# android - delete special file name with ( character

Tags: android

I run below code to delete a file in android but doesn't work:

origin file name:

```
/storage/emulated/0/concreteangelradioedit (1).mp3
```

I re-encode it to:

```
/storage/emulated/0/concreteangelradioedit%20%281%29.mp3
```

Code section:

```
 File file = new File(filename);
 file.delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a URL encoding, try escaping your characters. See what happens with the following

> /storage/emulated/0/concreteangelradioedit\ \(1\).mp3

Hah, stackoverflow is taking my escapings into effect, be sure there is a single `\` in front of the space, and each of the parenthesis.

Make sure you also have to following permission defined in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

*edit*

Huh... have you tried simply deleting the file name as is without the encoding?

```
File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/concreteangelradioedit (1).mp3");
f.delete();
```

Not android, but using java on my local machine that worked without a problem.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. `File.delete()` should return a boolean, true or false, whether or not the file was deleted successfully, what is the return value of this call? Are any exceptions thrown? Do you have the proper permissions defined in your manifest that allow you to read / write to the sd card?

Comment: When trying to delete the file, does LogCat provide any useful messages?

Comment: Please see my edit, have you tried simple deleting the file name as is? On my local machine, the spaces and parenthesis worked for me flawlessly without escaping or encoding.

Comment: Yes, I have added sdcard write permission. other files without ( character can be deleted successfully. when it delete fail, return value is false but no exception happen. so I don't know the exact failure reason till now. just add a quote for whole file path doesn't work also.